# I have 2 column A and B and I want to calculate if A is 80% of colunm B then yes

Tags: sql

I have 2 column A and B and I want to calculate if A is 80% of coulm B then  yes

Comment: This is not very clear. What does it mean "A is 80% of column B"? I assume that the value in A should be *at least* 80% of the value in column B (percent sound a bit like number of occurrences, which would have a completely different meaning). What does it mean "then yes"? Return "yes"? Filtering? Counting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MSSQL the try this:

```
CASE WHEN colA/ ColB = .8 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as ColName
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is a SQL Fiddle which I have added for your Reference.Here I have Created a table named table1 where both columns a and b are of decimal types. I have inserted sample data into the table and used the following query to compute whether column a is 80% of Column b. The query is as follows in MySQL

```
select a,b,if(0.8*b=a,'yes','no') "YES or NO" from table1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82149c/1)

Hope fully it will help you.